# sync dropbox and xampp htdocs in ubuntu linux excluding temporary files

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, synchronization, dropbox, htdocs

i downloaded and installed dropbox from official website. i was able to sync my htdocs folder with dropbox too.

but my question is, is there any way to prevent dropbox from syncing temporary files which are created while editing the code.

eg: if i create **"test.php"**, while saving code, it creates another temp file named **"test.php~"** that temp file is also synced. I didn't find any settings to get this done.

if anyone have any solution this problem, please help

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is configured to sync all files within a given directory (normally ~/Dropbox). It won't distinguish between temporary files and general files unfortunately. As best I can offer is pausing the sync whilst you're working, and resuming it after - but apart from that everything in the folder will sync.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to backup or share your working files. For codes, you can use `github` or `bitbucket` to save or share your files to the cloud. If it is your `htdocs` folder, then it is better to use `git` with `gitignore` then use dropbox to save your file. Dropbox does not have provision to ignore files. If you insist in using dropbox or google drive, you can pause it while you are working and sync after your work is complete and temp files are removed.